# Are composite indexes supported in Memgraph?

Tags: memgraphdb

Can I create index on more than one property for any given label? I am running query like:

```
MATCH (n:Node) WHERE n.id = xyz AND n.source = abc;
```

and I want to know whether I can create multiple property indexes and if not, is there a good way to query for nodes matching multiple properties?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Memgraph does not support composite indexes, but you can create multiple label-property indexes. For example, run

```
CREATE INDEX ON Node(id);
CREATE INDEX ON Node(source);
```

To check if they are properly created, run `SHOW INDEX INFO;`.

Use `EXPLAIN/PROFILE` query ([inspecting](https://memgraph.com/docs/memgraph/reference-guide/inspecting-queries) and [profiling](https://memgraph.com/docs/memgraph/reference-guide/profiling-queries) queries) to see different options and test the performance, maybe one label-property index is good enough.